# Task priority in celery with redis

Tags: python, celery, distributed

I would like to implement a distributed job execution system with celery. Given that rabbitMQ doesn't support priorities and I'm painfully needing this feature, I turned to celery+redis.

In my situation, the tasks are closely related to hardware, for example, task A could only run on Worker 1 since only the PC of Worker 1 has got the necessary hardware. I set the CONCURRENCY of each worker to 1 so that a worker will only run one task each time. Each task takes about 2 minites.

To implement the priority feature, first of all I tried adding `priority` argument when calling `apply_async()`, for example `apply_async(priority=0)` and `apply_async(priority=9)`. In this test I launched only one Worker with COCURRENCY=1, and kicked off 10 tasks one by one with different priorities. I expected to see the tasks kicked off by `apply_async(priority=0)` will run in priority, but unfortunately they're just started as the kicking-off order.

Then I try to do some work around. I cloned each task, so for each one I have task_high and task_low, decorated by `@celery.task(priority=0)` and `@celery.task(priority=1)`. Then I did the same test as above, this time it was better, when the kicking-off order is "HH-LLLL-HHHH", the real order comes out to be "HH-L-H-H-L-H-L-L-H". I suppose redis did some scheduling and balancing work here.

But this still can't meet my expectation. I hope to get an order like "HHHHHH-LLLL", because for some tasks I have only one proper machine with the necessary hardware and hope the high-priority task to run as soon as possible.

I've searched for other work around on the Internet, for example using two queues, one for high-priority tasks and the other for low-priority, and using 2 machines for the former and 1 machine for the latter. But since my hardware is quite limited, this doesn't work for me.

Could you please give some suggestions?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The Celery Redis transport does honor the priority field,
but Redis itself has no notion of priorities.

The priority support is implemented by creating n lists for each queue
and using that order in the BRPOP command.
I say `n` here because even though there are 10 (0-9) priority levels, these are
consolidated into 4 levels by default to save resources.
This means that a queue named `celery` will really be split into 4 queues:

```
['celery0', 'celery3`, `celery6`, `celery9`]
```

If you want more priority levels you can set the `priority_steps` transport option:

```
BROKER_TRANSPORT_OPTIONS = {
    'priority_steps': list(range(10)),
}
```

That said, note that this will never be as good as priorities implemented
at the server level, and may be approximate at best.  But it may still be good
enough for your application.

[Source.](https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/latest/userguide/routing.html#redis-message-priorities)

Comment: Thanks for the details, but what could I do to get an order as I want ? Should I just change the `priority_steps`?

Comment: You will just have try it out. With the default priority steps those 0 and 1's will be consolidated into 0 only.

Comment: OK thanks, I tried with priority 0 for task high and priority 9 for task low, now it seems much better, though sometimes some tasks with priority 9 still run prior to the ones with priority 0. I don't know if there's something wrong with my configurations or it's redis that did some balancing job.

Comment: As I say, it's not entirely reliable as long as the prioritization is not implemented on the server

Comment: This is not the correct answer... _and_ you should mention that you have copy+pasted the docs... even if you copied the wrong section (https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/routing.html#redis-message-priorities)

Answer (score 4):

Celery docs about redis message priorities is here [redis-message-priorities](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/routing.html#redis-message-priorities),you can customize priority levels.Take 10 for example:

1. set the priority_steps transport option

```
app.conf.broker_transport_options = {
    'priority_steps': list(range(10)),
    'queue_order_strategy': 'priority',
}
```

2. start celery worker in normal way

```py
celery -A tasks worker --loglevel=info
```

3. calling tasks,
   0 being highest priority and 9 being lowest priority

```py
custom_priority=5 
task.apply_async(args=[arg1, arg2], kwargs={'kwarg1': 'x', 'kwarg2': 'y'},priority=custom_priority)
```

Comment: How can I check that the correct priority was used when executing a task? I cannot find this via Redis or Celery.

Comment: Thanks for an elegant and quick solution