# Could someone please clarify the task priority usage in Celery tasks?

Tags: celery

The documentation says very little about the `priority` attribute. One of the rare documentation references says the following:

```
priority (int): The task priority, a number between 0 and 9.
  Defaults to the :attr:`priority` attribute.
```

(Ref: http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/_modules/celery/app/task.html#Task.apply_async )

However, if you go to the bottom of the following page - http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/calling.html - you will see:

> priority
> A number between 0 and 255, where 255 is the highest priority.
>
> Supported by: RabbitMQ, Redis (priority reversed, 0 is highest).

These two pieces of information contradict. Also, I would assume that the docstring is more up-to-date...

Question is which one is relevant, and more importantly: How are priorities ordered - does priority=0 mean highest priority, or not? Or it depends on the backend, as the docs page says...

I've also made a GitHub issue for this - https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/4599

**Update 1**: I have found the following in the kombu changelog for v4.0 (http://docs.celeryproject.org/projects/kombu/en/latest/changelog.html):

> Redis: Priority 0 is now lowest, 9 is highest. (backward incompatible)
>
> This to match how priorities in AMQP works.
>
> Fix contributed by Alex Koshelev.

Comment: Updated in 4.0.2 to revert to the pre-v4 behavior: https://github.com/celery/kombu/blob/baf488bdaff629036785536db1268c5419c1c37e/Changelog#L215.

Seems like a duplicate of this issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15239880/task-priority-in-celery-with-redis.

Comment: @phillbaker - that question (and askol’s answer) are from 2013. I don’t think this qualifies as a duplicate since things could have changed since.